# UIBezierPaths Not Showing in CALayer drawLayer inContext

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, quartz-graphics

I am using the code below to draw an arc into the **drawLayer** method of a custom `CALayer` class but nothing is displayed:

```
(void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx

{
    float r = self.bounds.size.width/2;

    CGContextClearRect(ctx, self.bounds); // clear layer
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

    //CGContextFillRect(ctx, layer.bounds);

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0) radius:r startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:M_PI_2 clockwise:NO];

    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Note that if I uncomment the `CGContextFillRect(ctx, layer.bounds)` line, a rectangle is properly rendered.

Comment: Missing a stroke color?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can see is that you don't set a stroke color (but a fill color)

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
```

When you configure a *fill* color it is used to *fill* the path. Same for a stroke color.

---

If you want to only want to either stroke or fill the path then you should use *either* `CGContextStrokePath` or `CGContextFillPath` but if you want to do both then you should use `CGContextDrawPath` with `kCGPathFillStroke` as the "drawing mode".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you. I finally decided to draw the arc outside the drawLayer method using the following code:

```
- (id) initWithLayer:(id)layer withRadius:(float)radius
{
  self = [super initWithLayer:layer];

  // ...

  self.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
  self.lineWidth = 10.0;

  return self;
}

- (void) update:(float)progress 
{
    // ....

    UIBezierPath *arcPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [arcPath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(r, r) radius:r  - self.lineWidth/2  startAngle:startAngle endAngle:nextAngle clockwise:YES];
    self.path = arcPath.CGPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all the arc drawing methods for both CGPath and UIBezierPath have a bug on 64 bit devices where they only work if the clockwise parameter is set to YES. I notice that your non-working code shows `clockwise:NO` and the working code has `clockwise:YES`.